# more dynamic melting with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I am looking for the most efficient form to transform

```
  ARTNR           FILGRP
1     1             9827
2     2             9348
3     3 9335, 9827, 9339
```

into this

```
  ARTNR      FILGRP
1     1      9827
2     2      9348
3     3      9335
4     3      9827
5     3      9339
```

I tried the following code and it works, but it is not elegant and has some shortcomings. :

```
setDT(artnrs)  
artnrs[, c("P1", "P2", "P3") := tstrsplit(FILGRP, ",", fixed=TRUE)] # 1)
artnrs <- melt(artnrs, c("ARTNR"), measure = patterns("^P")) # 2)
artnrs[,variable:=NULL] # 3)
artnrs <- na.omit(artnrs, cols="value") # 4)
names(artnrs)[2] <- "FILGRP" # 5)
```

- ad 1) splits the last column in three new ones. How can I make this dynamic and make it fit for five or ten?
- ad 2-5) rather clumpsy operations, could I chain this better?

It is based on `data.table` but performance is not that critical so an easy to understand `tidyverse` solution would be ok. But the fewer packages, the better.

Thanks!

`dput` output;

```
structure(list(ARTNR = c(1, 2, 3), FILGRP = c("9827", "9348", "9335, 9827, 9339")), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You'd want to use an `unlist` in there (not using `:=`). Or you can use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. Or you can use `separate_rows` from "tidyr".

Comment: Just to elaborate you can try any of the following `artnrs[, list(FILGRP = unlist(tstrsplit(FILGRP, ",", type.convert = TRUE))), ARTNR]`, or `cSplit(artnrs, "FILGRP", direction = "long")`, or `separate_rows(artnrs, FILGRP)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(ARTNR = c(1, 2, 3), FILGRP = c("9827", "9348", "9335, 9827, 9339")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- strsplit(df$FILGRP, split = ",")
df2 <- data.frame(ARTNR = rep(df$ARTNR, sapply(df2, length)), FILGRP = unlist(df2))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
setDT(DT)

melt( DT[, paste0( "v", 1:length(tstrsplit( DT$FILGRP, ", ") ) ) := tstrsplit( FILGRP, ", ") ],
      id.vars = "ARTNR", 
      measure.vars = patterns( "^v" ),
      value.name = "FILGRP" )[!is.na(FILGRP), .SD, .SDcols = c(1,3) ]


#    ARTNR FILGRP
# 1:     1   9827
# 2:     2   9348
# 3:     3   9335
# 4:     3   9827
# 5:     3   9339
```